# Trying to subset the column names in my dataframe in R

Tags: r, vector, subset

I want the column names 2 through 9, and 18 through 25 and i tried:

```
colnames(df)[2:9,18:25]
```

but it returns error of incorrect dimensions, how would i do this in a simple manner?

Comment: Try `colnames(df)[c(2:9,18:25)]`

Comment: @markus ahh of course, that works thanks!

Comment: @markus why don't you submit your comment as an answer so rholeepoly can mark it answered?